# Login and register button both validate user input

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am working on login and register form, both of the forms are doing their work perfectly. But I have a problem, whenever I click on register form it's check user input. It should not do that just simply redirect to registration form but it's not.

```
<form class="login-form" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control" runat="server" required=""></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" placeholder="Password..." type="password" class="form-control" runat="server" required=""></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnLogin" type="submit" class="btn" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="BtnLogin_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="BtnRegister" class="btn" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="BtnRegister_Click" />
</form>
```

What's causing the problem here any idea???

Comment: Your register button is submitting the form, as all ASP buttons do, and the `required` attribute is going to validate on a form submit. `CausesValidation` is an ASP.Net property but I'd assume the validation itself is simple HTML5 client-side validation.

Comment: how to stop it ?? @Santi

Comment: You could try not making it a button. If it just redirects, why not just... provide a link?

Comment: @J.Steen Server-side controls cannot be outside the form in ASP.Net. Though, depending on what the button does, it may not have to be a server-side control at all.

Comment: @Santi I haven't used WebForms in literally a decade. I forgot about the server-form part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your register button is submitting the form, as all ASP buttons do, and the `required` attribute of your inputs is going to validate on a form submit. `CausesValidation` won't do anything because it's an ASP.Net property (and to be used with ASP.Net validators), whereas the `required` attribute validation is an HTML5 client-side  event.

Try putting the [`formnovalidate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate) attribute on your Register button:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnRegister" class="btn" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="BtnRegister_Click" formnovalidate />
```

[**W3 Reference:**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formnovalidate)

> The `novalidate` and `formnovalidate` content attributes are [boolean attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). If present, they indicate that the form is not to be validated during submission.

---

### OR...

If your register button is a simple redirect, it does not need to be a server-side control. Just make it a link and style it like a button:

```css
a.register-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="/register.aspx" class="register-btn">Register</a>
```

Comment: still getting the same problem

Comment: Consider doing a view-source and providing the rendered HTML code in your question (rather than just the ASP) so that your example is runnable. Also, what is your register button actually doing? If it's simply redirecting to another page, why does it need to be a server-side control? And why not just a styled link instead of a button?